# How to restrict the bing visual search using python API to get results from custom/specific website?

Tags: python-3.x

Using [the bing python API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/quickstarts/python) I was able to extract results from multiple websites. Below is the code that I am using, but I want to get the similar images from one specific website. How can I restrict my search?

Code:

```
import requests, json

BASE_URI = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/visualsearch'
SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = 'Key'
imagePath = 'Image'

HEADERS = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': "Key"}'

file = {'image' : ('myfile', open(imagePath, 'rb'))}

def print_json(obj):
    """Print the object as json"""
    print(json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))

try:
    response = requests.post(BASE_URI, headers=HEADERS, files=file)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print_json(response.json())

except Exception as ex:
    raise ex
```

Comment: do you mean "search across internet" by "extract results from multiple websites"? If not, could you specify what multiple websites are searched?

Comment: Instead of getting the results/response from multiple websites. The search results should consist of results from only one website. Example: If I am searching for a similar item w.r.t checked shirt, I want the response consisting of results from one website (I.e. www.xyzsite.com)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/concepts/sending-queries) you submit an knowledge request in the POST call with this section:

```
  "knowledgeRequest" : {
  "filters" : {
    "site" : ""
  }
```

Where under "site" you can put the site you want to get results from.
This is also backed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bingvisualsearch/images/visualsearch):

> If you use the site: filter in the knowledge request, there is the chance that the response may contain adult content regardless of what the safeSearch query parameter is set to. Use site: only if you are aware of the content on the site and your scenario supports the possibility of adult content.